# return an array refrence variable from a method?

Tags: java

Consider the follwing code:

```
class Box {
    int size;

    Box(int s) { 
        size = s; 
    }
}

public class Laser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box b1 = new Box(5);
        Box[] ba = go(b1, new Box(6));
        ba[0] = b1;
        for (Box b : ba) {
            System.out.print(b.size + " ");
        }
    }

    static Box[] go(Box b1, Box b2) {
        b1.size = 4;
        Box[] ma = {b2, b1};
        return ma;
    }
}
```

What is the result? 
i solved it to be 5 4 but it's not the right one, the right answer is 4 4, how that come?

Comment: Half the game seems to be to fix the indentation. I won't play.

Comment: Please, format indentation properly

Comment: i fixed the indentation for you

Comment: b1 gets passed into go, where its size variable gets set to 4. When go returns, ba has [5, 4], and b1 has 4. Then you stick b1 in ba[0] and get [4, 4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `go` method changes the size of your `b1` box to 4, and places it at index 1 in the array. Then the main method also sets it at index 0. So the array contains two references to `b1`, whose size is 4.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the array `ba` has two instances of b1. Both of which are size 4.

Answer (score 0):

Step through the code with a debugger, comparing your results with the actual results along the way. This will show you where your solutions diverge!

`go()` returns `{b2,b1}`. You then set the first entry in the array to `b1`, leaving you with `{b1,b1}`, which will print the result you are getting.